# Using queue for waitlist application giving me error when I display my data

Tags: java, queue

just completed a restaurant waitlist program using Java and I'm having some issues. I used a queue with a linked list, and when I click display on my GUI it is giving me this error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at waitlist.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:74)
at waitlist.LinkedListStack.dequeue(LinkedListStack.java:10)
at waitlist.WaitListForm.btnDisplayActionPerformed(WaitListForm.java:189)
at waitlist.WaitListForm.access$100(WaitListForm.java:6)
at waitlist.WaitListForm$2.actionPerformed(WaitListForm.java:46)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Everything else runs fine.

This is the LinkedList.java:74

```
public E removeFirst() {
    if (isEmpty() ) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        ***E answer = head.getElement();***
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
        if (size == 0) {
            tail = null; // list is now empty
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

And this is LinkedListStack.java:10

```
**public int size() {**
        return list.getSize();
    }
```

And this is WaitlistForm.java:189

```
private void btnDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        String result;
        int s;
        int size = stack.size();
        lstOutput.removeAll();
        for (s = 0; s < size; s++) {
            ***result = (String)stack.dequeue();***
            lstOutput.add(result);


        }
    }
```

Here is my code;

LinkedList.java

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
private int size;
private Node<E> head;
private Node<E> tail;

// default constructor
public LinkedList() {
    size = 0;
    head = null;
    tail = null;
}

// read-only property
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    // replaces an if/else
    return (size == 0);
}

// return but not remove head of the list
public E first() {
    if ( isEmpty() ) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return head.getElement();
    }
}

public E last() {
    if ( isEmpty() ) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return tail.getElement();
    }
}

public void addFirst(E e) {
    // create a new node and make it the new head of the list
    head = new Node<>(e, head);

    if (size == 0) {
        tail = head; // special case first item in the list
    }

    size++;
}

public void addLast(E e) {
    // create a new node and add to the tail of the list
    Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, null);
    if (size == 0) {
        tail = head; // special case for the first item
    }
    else {
        tail.setNext(newest);
    }

    tail = newest;
    size++;
}

public E removeFirst() {
    if (isEmpty() ) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        E answer = head.getElement();
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
        if (size == 0) {
            tail = null; // list is now empty
        }
        return answer;
    }
}


// nested class
public class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    // custom constructor
    public Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
        element = e;
        next = n;
    }

    // get element
    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
        next = n;
    }
} // end nested node class

} // end of LinkedList
```

LinkedListStack.java

```
public class LinkedListStack<E> implements QueueInterface<E> {

    private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<>(); // an empty list

    public LinkedListStack() {
    } // new queue relies on the initially empty list

    public int size() {
        return list.getSize();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public void enqueue(E element) {
        list.addLast(element);
    }

    public E first() {
        return list.first();
    }

    public E dequeue() {
        return list.removeFirst();
    }
}
```

QueueInterface.java

```
public interface QueueInterface<E> {

    int size();

    boolean isEmpty();

    // adds an item to the stack
    void enqueue(E e);

    // return but not remove the top item on the stack
    E first();

    // remove item at the top of the stack
    E dequeue();  
}
```

And here is my form (WaitlistForm.java)

```
int Highest = 0;
    int Wait = 0;

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        Random rand = new Random();

        int  time = rand.nextInt(30) + 1;

        int partySize = Integer.parseInt(txtSize.getText());

        int total = IntStream.of(time).sum();

        String name = txtName.getText();

        if (partySize > Highest){
            txtAvg.setText(String.valueOf(partySize));
            txtTotal.setText(name);
            Highest = partySize;

        }
        String result = " Name: " + txtName.getText() + "  Party Size: " + partySize + "  Wait Time: " + time + " minutes.";

            stack.enqueue(result);
            Wait++;

    }                                      

    private void btnDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        String result;
        int s;
        int size = stack.size();
        lstOutput.removeAll();
        for (s = 0; s < size; s++) {
            result = (String)stack.dequeue();
            lstOutput.add(result);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because your underlying `LinkedList` in the `LinkedListStack` is not being constructed correctly. The biggest hint is that the problematic `NullPointerException` on that line suggests that the value of `head` is null, even though your `isEmpty()` message returned false. This means your list has `head = null`, and `size != 0`.

Your `LinkedListStack` adds elements to the list by calling the `addLast()` method, which I've re-pasted here:

```
public void addLast(E e) {
    // create a new node and add to the tail of the list
    Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, null);
    if (size == 0) {
        tail = head; // special case for the first item
    }
    else {
        tail.setNext(newest);
    }

    tail = newest;
    size++;
}
```

Try to walk through what happens when you add the first element. Both `head` and `tail` will be null. You enter your special case "if" branch, and set `tail = head`. This doesn't do anything since both are already null. Then you continue and set `tail` to `newest`, but you never set `head` anywhere. This means that `head` will always be null, regardless of how many elements you add to your data structure. To fix it, you might try something like:

```
public void addLast(E e) {
    // create a new node and add to the tail of the list
    Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, null);
    if (size == 0) {   // special case for the first item
        head = newest; // now head points to the new node
    }
    else {
        tail.setNext(newest);
    }

    tail = newest;
    size++;
}
```

I've made the bare minimum changes to your code so you can get a better understanding of why it was broken before. Notice how now for the first element, we point `head` to the newest node.

A couple of other things I noticed:

- I noticed a similar bug in `addFirst`. I think if you understand the reason `addLast` was broken, you should be able to easily come up with the fix.
- I think you might have your concept of a `Stack` and a `Queue` mixed up. Generally Stacks are "last in, first out", while Queues are "first in, first out". The `LinkedListStack` class you've created calls `addLast` to "push" elements onto the stack, and `removeFirst` to "pop" elements from the stack. This means that your data structure looks a lot like a typical Queue, not a Stack.